# R: plotting posterior classification probabilities of a linear discriminant analysis in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, ggbiplot

Using `ggord` one can make nice linear discriminant analysis `ggplot2` biplots (cf chapter 11, Fig 11.5 in "Biplots in practice" by M. Greenacre), as in

```
library(MASS)
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("fawda123/ggord")
library(ggord)
data(iris)
ord <- lda(Species ~ ., iris, prior = rep(1, 3)/3)
ggord(ord, iris$Species)
```

[image]

I would also like to add the classification regions (shown as solid regions of the same colour as their respective group with say alpha=0.5) or the posterior probabilities of class membership (with alpha then varying according to this posterior probability and the same colour as used for each group) (as can be done in `BiplotGUI`, but I am looking for a `ggplot2` solution). Would anyone know how to do this with `ggplot2`, perhaps using `geom_tile` ?

EDIT: below someone asks how to calculate the posterior classification probabilities & predicted classes. This goes like this:

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
fit <- lda(Species ~ ., data = iris, prior = rep(1, 3)/3)
datPred <- data.frame(Species=predict(fit)$class,predict(fit)$x)
#Create decision boundaries
fit2 <- lda(Species ~ LD1 + LD2, data=datPred, prior = rep(1, 3)/3)
ld1lim <- expand_range(c(min(datPred$LD1),max(datPred$LD1)),mul=0.05)
ld2lim <- expand_range(c(min(datPred$LD2),max(datPred$LD2)),mul=0.05)
ld1 <- seq(ld1lim[[1]], ld1lim[[2]], length.out=300)
ld2 <- seq(ld2lim[[1]], ld1lim[[2]], length.out=300)
newdat <- expand.grid(list(LD1=ld1,LD2=ld2))
preds <-predict(fit2,newdata=newdat)
predclass <- preds$class
postprob <- preds$posterior
df <- data.frame(x=newdat$LD1, y=newdat$LD2, class=predclass)
df$classnum <- as.numeric(df$class)
df <- cbind(df,postprob)
head(df)

           x        y     class classnum       setosa   versicolor virginica
1 -10.122541 -2.91246 virginica        3 5.417906e-66 1.805470e-10         1
2 -10.052563 -2.91246 virginica        3 1.428691e-65 2.418658e-10         1
3  -9.982585 -2.91246 virginica        3 3.767428e-65 3.240102e-10         1
4  -9.912606 -2.91246 virginica        3 9.934630e-65 4.340531e-10         1
5  -9.842628 -2.91246 virginica        3 2.619741e-64 5.814697e-10         1
6  -9.772650 -2.91246 virginica        3 6.908204e-64 7.789531e-10         1

colorfun <- function(n,l=65,c=100) { hues = seq(15, 375, length=n+1); hcl(h=hues, l=l, c=c)[1:n] } # default ggplot2 colours
colors <- colorfun(3)
colorslight <- colorfun(3,l=90,c=50)
ggplot(datPred, aes(x=LD1, y=LD2) ) +
    geom_raster(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = factor(class)),alpha=0.7,show_guide=FALSE) +
    geom_contour(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=classnum), colour="red2", alpha=0.5, breaks=c(1.5,2.5)) +
    geom_point(data = datPred, size = 3, aes(pch = Species,  colour=Species)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = ld1lim, expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = ld2lim, expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=colorslight,guide=F)
```

[image]

(well not totally sure this approach for showing classification boundaries using contours/breaks at 1.5 and 2.5 is always correct - it is correct for the boundary between species 1 and 2 and species 2 and 3, but not if the region of species 1 would be next to species 3, as I would get two boundaries there then - maybe I would have to use the approach used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260576/plot-decision-boundaries-with-ggplot2) where each boundary between each species pair is considered separately)

This gets me as far as plotting the classification regions. I am looking for a solution though to also plot the actual posterior classification probabilities for each species at each coordinate, using alpha (opaqueness) proportional to the posterior classification probability for each species, and a species-specific colour. In other words, with a stack of three images superimposed. As alpha blending in ggplot2 is known to be [order-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078774/overlay-two-ggplot2-stat-density2d-plots-with-alpha-channels), I think the colours of this stack would have to calculated beforehand though, and plotted using something like

```
qplot(x, y, data=mydata, fill=rgb, geom="raster") + scale_fill_identity()
```

[Here is a SAS example of what I am after](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/discrim.htm):

[image]

Would anyone know how to do this perhaps? Or does anyone have any thoughts on how to best represent these posterior classification probabilities?

Note that the method should work for any number of groups, not just for this specific example.

Comment: can you add an example of your data layout?

Comment: ah, Iris, Forget my question :-)

Comment: Can you extract the data (classification regions, posterior probabilities) that should be plotted?

Comment: I've now added that bit and clarified my question a bit better!

Comment: Do you mean `expand_limits()` instead of `expand_range()` ?

Comment: Yes that would work too I guess, although I like scales::expand_range()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also just came up with the following easy solution: just make a column in `df` where class predictions are made stochastically, according to the posterior probabilities, which then results in dithering in uncertain regions, e.g. as in

```
fit = lda(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = iris, prior = rep(1, 3)/3)
ld1lim <- expand_range(c(min(datPred$LD1),max(datPred$LD1)),mul=0.5)
ld2lim <- expand_range(c(min(datPred$LD2),max(datPred$LD2)),mul=0.5)
```

rest as above, and inserting

```
lvls=unique(df$class)
df$classpprob=apply(df[,as.character(lvls)],1,function(row) sample(lvls,1,prob=row))

p=ggplot(datPred, aes(x=LD1, y=LD2) ) +
  geom_raster(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = factor(classpprob)),hpad=0, vpad=0, alpha=0.7,show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = datPred, size = 3, aes(pch = Group,  colour=Group)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorslight,guide=F) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=rngs[[1]], expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=rngs[[2]], expand=c(0,0))
```

gives me
[image]

A lot easier and clearer than starting to mix colours in some additive or subtractive fashion anyway (which is the part where I still had trouble, and which apparently is not so trivial to do well).

Answer (score 13):

I suppose the easiest way will be to show the posterior probabilities. It is pretty straightforward for your case:

```
datPred$maxProb <- apply(predict(fit)$posterior, 1, max)
ggplot(datPred, aes(x=LD1, y=LD2) ) +
  geom_raster(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = factor(class)),alpha=0.7,show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_contour(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=classnum), colour="red2", alpha=0.5, breaks=c(1.5,2.5)) +
  geom_point(data = datPred, size = 3, aes(pch = Species,  colour=Species, alpha = maxProb)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = ld1lim, expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = ld2lim, expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorslight, guide=F)
```

[image]

You can see the points blend in at blue-green border.

Comment: nice possible solution - thanks for that! Although I would prefer not to shade my points as e.g. I was still thinking of highlighting incorrectly classified ones in red, plus maybe not all parts of the regions are well presented by points. So still looking for a solution to show them using alpha shading in the shaded background part to get something like the SAS output. Nevertheless +1 !