# R: How to calculate the threshold for LDA in the case of three classes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-science, linear-discriminant

The result of discriminant analysis for the three classes are two discriminant functions **LD1** and **LD2**.

In the case of two classes, there is one discriminant function **LD1**, and the threshold of discrimination can be calculated as follows:

[image: formula]

**M1** is the mean value of **LD1** estimates for class 1, and **M2** for class 2.

Please, help me understand how, with **LD1** and **LD2**, calculated threshold of discrimination for the case of three classes.

In other words, how I can find the equations of these thresholds lines on a graph?

[image]

The code for this plot was taken from here [R: plotting posterior classification probabilities of a linear discriminant analysis in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893423/r-plotting-posterior-classification-probabilities-of-a-linear-discriminant-anal)

Comment: Given this question isn't about a programming issue but the mathematics behind LDA, this question is a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @caldwellst I understand, but guided by the fact that plotting with that thresholds is a programming topic, I came to the conclusion that maybe someone from the programmers will be able to help me with the code to search for thresholds equations, since mathematicians are not very active in this topic.