# Unable to plot Decision Boundary in R with geom_contour()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, knn

I know that there are several similar questions about it but I am still struggling to understand the concept behind it.

I predicted classes ("true" and "false") based on a knn:

```
hype_knn_prediction = knn(hype_quant_train[,2:3], hype_quant_test[,2:3], cl = hype_quant_train$Selected, k = k)
```

and I am also able to plot the test data:

```
ggplot(hype_quant_test, aes(x= Comments, y= Votings, color = Selected, shape = Selected)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  labs(y="Votes", x = "Comments")+
  ggtitle("Testdata")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[Plot of test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Odi.png)

now I would like to add the decision boundary of the classes to the plot of the test data. Therefore I added the `hype_knn_prediction` as a column to the `hype_quant_test` data frame. But when I add `geom_contour(data=hype_quant_test, aes(x=Comments, y=Votings, z= as.numberic(Selected)), breaks=c(0,.5))` to the plot I get the following message:
**Computation failed in stat_contour(): Number of x coordinates must match number of columns in density matrix.**

How can I resolve the issue? I assume I have to transform some data but don't know how

**EDIT**

training data:

```
   Selected  Votings          Comments
1      true  0.2348563517    0.162454874
2     false  0.0027691243    0.001805054
3     false  0.0136725511    0.027075812
4     false  0.1128418138    0.077617329
5     false  0.0529595016    0.016245487
6     false  0.0190377293    0.012635379
7     false  0.0231914157    0.001805054
8     false  0.3367947387    0.019855596
9     false  0.0036344756    0.005415162
10    false  0.0051921080    0.005415162
11    false  0.0202492212    0.014440433
12    false  0.0178262375    0.007220217
13    false  0.0029421945    0.010830325
14    false  0.0680166147    0.036101083
15    false  0.0053651783    0.003610108
16    false  0.2397023191    0.034296029
17    false  0.0001730703    0.000000000
18    false  0.0228452752    0.023465704
19    false  0.0129802700    0.000000000
20    false  0.0192107996    0.018050542
21    false  0.0010384216    0.000000000
22    false  0.0129802700    0.005415162
23    false  0.0000000000    0.000000000
24    false  0.0134994808    0.003610108
25    false  0.0742471443    0.039711191
26    false  0.0256143994    0.009025271
27    false  0.0039806161    0.001805054
28     true  0.4110418830    0.050541516
29    false  0.0114226376    0.063176895
30    false  0.0185185185    0.016245487
31    false  0.0051921080    0.003610108
32    false  0.1952232606    0.021660650
33    false  0.1138802354    0.012635379
34    false  0.0048459675    0.016245487
35    false  0.0242298373    0.009025271
36    false  0.0167878159    0.001805054
37    false  0.0039806161    0.001805054
38     true  0.7727587400    0.146209386
39    false  0.0154032537    0.000000000
40    false  0.0057113188    0.007220217
41    false  0.0038075459    0.000000000
42    false  0.0046728972    0.001805054
43    false  0.0152301835    0.003610108
44    false  0.0408445829    0.025270758
45    false  0.0131533403    0.007220217
46    false  0.0578054690    0.037906137
47    false  0.0046728972    0.005415162
48    false  0.0001730703    0.001805054
49    false  0.1169955002    0.122743682
50    false  0.0044998269    0.003610108
51    false  0.0000000000    0.000000000
52    false  0.1439944618    0.036101083
53    false  0.0072689512    0.005415162
54    false  0.0064035999    0.009025271
55    false  0.0614399446    0.027075812
56    false  0.0719972309    0.005415162
57     true  0.3418137764    0.018050542
58    false  0.0117687781    0.012635379
59    false  0.0072689512    0.014440433
60     true  0.0313257182    0.018050542
61    false  0.1021114573    0.019855596
62    false  0.0024229837    0.003610108
63    false  0.0072689512    0.000000000
64    false  0.0169608861    0.003610108
65    false  0.0340948425    0.014440433
66     true  0.7069920388    0.332129964
67     true  0.7377985462    0.175090253
68    false  0.0919003115    0.007220217
69    false  0.0065766701    0.001805054
70    false  0.0401523018    0.027075812
71    false  0.0223260644    0.005415162
72    false  0.0635167878    0.018050542
73    false  0.0013845621    0.000000000
74    false  0.0060574593    0.000000000
75     true  0.6102457598    0.909747292
76    false  0.0022499135    0.001805054
77    false  0.0316718588    0.007220217
78    false  0.0019037729    0.000000000
79     true  1.0000000000    1.000000000
80    false  0.0240567670    0.016245487
```

Test data after adding prediction column:

```
   Selected   Votings          Comments   Prediction
1     false   0.329525787    0.023465704      false
2     false   0.299930772    0.075812274      false
3      true   0.962443752    0.178700361       true
4     false   0.032191070    0.001805054      false
5     false   0.036863967    0.025270758      false
6     false   0.014884043    0.005415162      false
7     false   0.034787124    0.005415162      false
8     false   0.007615092    0.000000000      false
9     false   0.005538249    0.000000000      false
10    false   0.006403600    0.005415162      false
11    false   0.006749740    0.005415162      false
12    false   0.048286604    0.072202166      false
13    false   0.057286258    0.021660650      false
14    false   0.067324334    0.012635379      false
15    false   0.004153686    0.001805054      false
16    false   0.004845967    0.003610108      false
17    false   0.089131187    0.055956679      false
18    false   0.010384216    0.001805054      false
19    false   0.040671513    0.021660650      false
20    false   0.001903773    0.001805054      false
```

**EDIT**

I tried to test the plotting with the default Iris data but the message is still the same:

```
library(datasets)
library(class)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)

iris_df = as.data.frame(iris)

normalize = function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

iris_df$Sepal.Length = normalize(iris_df$Sepal.Length)
iris_df$Sepal.Width = normalize(iris_df$Sepal.Width)
iris_df$Petal.Length = normalize(iris_df$Petal.Length)
iris_df$Petal.Width = normalize(iris_df$Petal.Width)

set.seed(1234)

#sampling
sample = sample(nrow(iris_df), nrow(iris_df)*0.8, replace = FALSE)

#Training data
iris_train=iris_df[sample,]

#Testdata
iris_test=iris_df[-sample,]


ggplot(iris_train, aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

ggplot(iris_test, aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

k = round(sqrt(nrow(iris_train)))


knn_predict = knn(iris_train[,1:4], iris_test[,1:4], cl = iris_train$Species, k = k)

iris_test$Prediction = knn_predict

confusionMatrix(iris_test$Prediction, iris_test$Species)

ggplot(iris_test, aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_contour(data = iris_test, aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width, z = as.numeric(Prediction)),breaks = c(0,.5))
```

*Computation failed in `stat_contour()`:
Number of x coordinates must match number of columns in density matrix.*

Comment: Could you give us either a sufficient snippet of the input data to replicate the issue, or replicate your issue with a standard dataset (for example iris)? It's hard to see where the problem lies if we can't replicate it.

Comment: @teunbrand, I added the training and test data to as well as the predicted classes to the question. I hope this helps to replicate the issue.

Comment: I can replicate your error. The problem seems mostly related that there is only 1 predicted value `true` so the contour cannot really use that. Also, I'm not exactly sure that a decision boundary is best illustrated with a contour plot.

Comment: @teunbrand, I tried to test it with the iris data set but the error is still the same. I assume that it has something to do with the grid of the plot but unfortunately I don't understand the solution given in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260576/plot-decision-boundaries-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a key part of the `geom_contour` approach that I don't see happening in your iris code is performing the predictions on a matrix of variables. Here is how you could make one. I didn't do anything too fancy with the preprocessing.

```r
library(class)
library(ggplot2)

train <- sample(150, 75)

train_dat <- iris[train, -5]
test_dat <- iris[-train, -5]

vars <- c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")

# First make a grid
n <- 40
pred.mat <- expand.grid(
  Sepal.Width = with(iris, seq(min(Sepal.Width), max(Sepal.Width), length.out = n)),
  Sepal.Length = with(iris, seq(min(Sepal.Length), max(Sepal.Length), length.out = n))
)

# Then ask for prediction on the grid
pred.mat$pred <- knn(train_dat[, vars], pred.mat, cl = iris$Species[train], k = 3)

# Use grid as input for geom_contour
ggplot(pred.mat, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = as.numeric(pred == "setosa"), 
                   colour = "setosa"), 
               breaks = 0.5) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = as.numeric(pred == "virginica"), 
                   colour = "virginica"), 
               breaks = 0.5) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = as.numeric(pred == "versicolor"), 
                   color = "versicolor"), 
               breaks = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I replicated your code and it works well, but could you explain some more details of it? Why do we have to create an additional grid? What is it exactly doing? Especially the grid is something I find in other solutions but I struggle to understand its connection to geom_contour()

Comment: The contours are calculed for a grid of values, that is also how the contours work if you use `stat_density2d()`. By making the grid and passing that through the knn prediction, you get xy locations for where the knn would predict a category would occur, which you can feed into the contours.

Comment: So, just to get the intuition behind it. We create a  new grid that ranges from the min to the max of both variables we want to plot. In this case, n=40 ist just an arbitrarily chosen number to decide how many points we want to have in the grid. Then we apply knn NOT on the test data but on the whole grid based on the training set, right? After that we create a plot that shows the whole iris data set but as an additional layer we also plot the whole grid which was classified by the knn?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct to me. If you reason that to know a decision boundary you need to know where an algorithm makes what decision and -you can't get that boundary algebraically- it would make sense to ask the algorithm what decisions it makes in an n x n grid. Yes 40 is arbitrary, it would depend how finegrained you want your boundaries. For the last point, we don't plot the grid per se, we use the grid as data for contours, which finds boundaries.