# Error in Summary.factor() when creating contour plot

Tags: r

```r
# Superimpose the decision boundary on the scatterplot of GPA vs. GMAT
ggplot(train, aes(x = GPA, y = GMAT, color = Group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Scatterplot of GPA vs. GMAT by Group with LDA Decision Boundary") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = predict(lda.fit, data.frame(GPA, GMAT))$class),
               bins = 2, alpha = 0.5)
```

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : 
  ‘range’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: You haven't shown us a [mcve], but `predict(lda.fit, ...)` returns a factor variable. You can't use that as the z variable for a contour plot.  What are you trying to do?  Plot decision boundaries?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260576/plot-decision-boundaries-with-ggplot2

Comment: yes i am trying to plot decision boundaries

Comment: lda.fit <- lda(Group ~ GPA + GMAT, data = train)

Comment: train <- admission[admission$Group != "border", ]

Comment: Right, this is not a **reproducible** example - we need to know where "admission" comes from.  You could probably use the example from `?predict.lda` as the starting point of a reproducible example ...  (Does looking at the question/answer I linked above help you solve your problem?)